# Create two files and copy the content of one file in other and displaying it on the screen[C++]

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{ 
    fstream file; 

    // Input stream class to 
    // operate on files. 
    ifstream ifile("file.txt", ios::in); 

    // Output stream class to 
    // operate on files. 
    ofstream ofile("file2.txt", ios::out | ios::app); 

    // check if file exists 
    if (!ifile.is_open()) { 

        // file not found (i.e, not opened). 
        // Print an error message. 
        cout << "file not found"; 
    } 
    else { 
        // then add more lines to 
        // the file if need be 
        ofile << ifile.rdbuf(); 
    } 
    string word; 

    // opening file 
    file.open("file2.txt"); 

    // extracting words form the file 
    while (file >> word) { 

        // displaying content of 
        // destination file 
        cout << word << " ";
    }
```

How to create file in this code by the respective names given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully I understood your quesiton correctly. If so:

```
std::ifstream instream("in.txt"); // create input stream
std::ofstream outstream("out.txt"); // create output stream
std::string line;
while (std::getline(instream, line)) // read line by line till eof
{
    outstream << line << std::endl; // insert the line into output stream
    std::cout << line << std::endl; // print the line to stdout
}
```

Comment: @ツJediRebellion Added some comments

Comment: @theWiseBro you are not writing any line breaks into the output file. `getline()` swallows the line breaks from the source file, so you need to write your own line breaks to the output file, just like you are for `cout`, eg `outstream << line << '\n'; `

Comment: Here you have to create two files using fstream and then you have to copy the content of one file to other and hence display the file onto the screen.. Hopefully you understood the question

Comment: @ツJediRebellion yup. this does just that. copies from file to another and prints it on the go as well.